# AWS getting all Users from aws cognitio with JS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

how can I get all Users from aws cognito?

I found this: list Users
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property

```
    var cognito = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;

    cognito.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
```

But when I do this I got this error:

No reagon defined ...

also tried this:

```
  AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'eu-central-1:',
        Logins: {
            'cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
        }
    });
```

here I got result is not defined ...

how can I fetch all Users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an working example:

```
let params = {
        UserPoolId: '<<PoolID>>',
        AttributesToGet: [
            'email',
            'family_name',
            'given_name',
            'custom:client',
            'phone_number'
        ],
        Limit: 0,
    };
    this.awsSDKAuth().listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log(data.Users);
        }
    });
```